# $|A|+|B| - 1 \leq |A+B| \leq |A| \cdot |B|$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A, B$ be finite sets of integers. We define $A+B = \{a + b: a \in A, b \in B\}$. Show that $$|A|+|B|-1 \leq |A+B| \leq |A| \cdot |B|.$$
My attempt: Right inequality seems obvious because of case when for every pair $(a,b)$, where $a \in A, b \in B$, sums $a+b$ are different. We have $|A| \cdot |B|$ such pairs.
However, I keep struggling with left inequality. So far, I proved that
$|A+B| \geq \max\{|A|, |B|\}$  (=|A|, let's say). For fixed $b \in B$ we have $\{b + a: a \in A\} \subset A+B$, thus $|A| \leq |A+B|$.

It's not enough, though. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea that for fixed $b \in B$, $\{b+a : a \in A\}$ gives you $|A|$ elements of $A+B$ is a good one.  Now suppose the $b$ you fixed is the smallest element of $B$.  Can you come up with $|B|-1$ more elements of $A+B$ that are different from the ones you've already listed?

Comment: $\{a+b: b \in B\}$, where $a$ is the largest element in $A$, should give us these elements. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $a = \min(A)$ and $b = \max(B)$, what is $(a + B) \cap (A + b)$?

Comment: It's a+b. Thank you, I get it now :)